# why function .view(batch_size,-1) gives the same outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I am a freshman in neural network and I have built a vgg16 network.But in every batch all the inputs leads to the same outputs.So I checked the output of every layer and finally found that x=x.view(batch_size,-1) gives the same outputs!I have no idea why this would happen. here are part of my code:

```
class VGG16(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VGG16, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 64, padding=1, kernel_size=3)              #kernel
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 64, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 128, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv4 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 128, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv5 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 256, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv6 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 256, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv7 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 256, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv8 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 512, padding=1 ,kernel_size=3)
        self.conv9 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv10 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv11 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv12 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv13 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, padding=1, kernel_size=3)
        self.pooling = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2)                                        #pool
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(25088, 4096)                                     # 7 * 7 * 512 = 25088
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 4096)
        self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(4096, 2)

    def forward(self,x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))                                                #layer1
        x = self.pooling(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))                                  #layer2
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))                                                #layer3
        x = self.pooling(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))                                  #layer4
        x = F.relu(self.conv5(x))                                                #layer5
        x = F.relu(self.conv6(x))                                                #layer6
        x = self.pooling(F.relu(self.conv7(x)))                                  #layer7
        x = F.relu(self.conv8(x))                                                #layer8
        x = F.relu(self.conv9(x))                                                #layer9
        x = self.pooling(F.relu(self.conv10(x)))                                 #layer10
        x = F.relu(self.conv11(x))                                               #layer11
        x = F.relu(self.conv12(x))                                               #layer12
        x = self.pooling(F.relu(self.conv13(x)))                                 #layer13
        x = x.view(batch_size,-1)                                                #flatten
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

this is the training part:

```
def train(epoch):
running_loss = 0.0
for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_loader,0):
    inputs, true_labels = data
    optimizer.zero_grad()                        #clear the optimizer to avoid accumulating of grad
    #forward
    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, true_labels)
    #backward
    loss.backward()
    #update
    optimizer.step()
    running_loss += loss.item()

    #output the train result every 10 loop
    if (batch_idx + 1) % 10 == 0:
        print('[%d %5d] loss: %.3f' %(epoch + 1, batch_idx + 1, running_loss/10 ))
        running_loss = 0.0
```

this is the outputs of layer13(before view):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk6ZT.png)

this is the outputs of x.view :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9QIT.png)

I am searching for a long time on net.But no use.Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: for this plz post your training code...not the model...(model is fine)

Comment: I have posted my training code and some outputs

Comment: hey bro , its correct...! it just changes you dimension...from 4D to 2D.....(i.e flattening)

Answer (score 0):

Use of view() method

```
import torch
torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).view(3,2)
#tensor([[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]])
```

Hence no change in tensor value..it will just change its `shape`